# Вывод содержимое поля типа TEXT в div

Tags: html

Имеется таблица с полями `id, fname, name и history (TEXT)`. На странице имеется `2 div-блока`. На первый `div (id="div1")` с помощью запроса выводится `fname` и `name` в виде таблицы.
Как организовать, чтобы при клике на строку таблицы в `div (id="div2")` выводился содержимое поля `history` соответствующей строки?

```html
<div class='klasdiv1' id='div1'>
  <?php
    $conn1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "my_mt");
    $result1=mysqli_query($conn1, "SELECT * FROM stable");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

        echo("<table class='nogap'>");
            echo("<th>");
                    echo("Фамилия");
            echo("</th>");
            echo("<th>");
                    echo("Имя");
            echo("</th>");
            echo("</tr>");
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
                {
            echo("<tbody>");
    ?>
    <tr id='<?php echo $row[' id '];?>'>
      <td class='stroka_table'><input type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class='stroka_table' style='text-align: center;'>
        <?php echo $row['id']?>
      </td>
      <?php
                echo("<td class='stroka_table'>".$row['fname']."</td>");                 
                echo("<td class='stroka_table'>".$row['name']."</td>");
            echo("</tr>");
            echo("</tbody>");
                }
        echo("</table>");
    ?>
</div>
<div class='klasdiv2' id='div2'>
</div>
```

Comment: Выложи код в снипет, чтобы вопрос не выглядел абстрактно, не у всех же развито воображение, как у тебя...

Comment: Извините, я впервые на этом форуме. Air я Ваш код не вижу.

Comment: Какой код?......

Comment: Извините я Вас неправильно понял. Скорее всего решение данного вопроса слишком прост, что-то я недопонимаю. В формуах не могу найти подобную проблему.